# Excel freezing when VBA tries to open another workbook located on OneDrive

Tags: excel, vba, onedrive

I have a master "data dump" in OneDrive where I drop unfiltered data from our CRM. Then using Advanced Filter in VBA to break out individual sales rep data, then opening their workbooks (in a sub folder on OneDrive) and pasting that data.

When I first built it, it worked totally fine. Now, though, Excel completely freezes at the line when trying to open the other workbook.

So: why is it doing this? Is it a VBA problem or a OneDrive problem? Is there a better solution for DataDump => Filter => Rep doc?

The line where it freezes:

```
Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path + "\Inside Sales Dashboards\" + name + ".xlsx"
```

Comment: You should use ```&``` to concatenate not ```+```, it can do weird things, though I'm not sure that would cause it to freeze.

Comment: I changed that, thanks. I doubt that was related, as it still crashed immediately upon reaching that line.

Comment: Start small and work your way up - try opening a local file with the full path being a string. Debug.print the string you think you're opening. Try to open that exact path. All of this will help you narrow down your problem

Comment: Your Q title says Excel "crashes", your text says "freezes".  These aren't the same thing, so which is it?

Comment: It goes not responding and never returns

Comment: @chrisneilsen Why remove the first sentence in your edit? Oftentimes questions suffer from an X/Y problem issue where the OP is directing all their efforts at a single path, while another path would lead to the same outcome, but in a better way. Thus, my first sentence.
Also, why delete the excel-vba tag? I followed the meta post and added the excel and vba tags in addition, as the notice requests.

Comment: Can you check what `ThisWorkbook.Path` returns in this case?